# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I'm using a gridlayoutmanager for the recyclerview in my app
With spanCount = 1 , what is the best way to  make the span count change based on the device's screen size ( to make it look good on tablets and large phones )

Comment: Learn how to use media queries to control the layout depending on the different browser/device sizes. Also, you're more likely to get help on this website if you try something first and come to ask coding-related questions.